# Download prices with python

Tags: python

I have tried this before. I'm completely at a loss for ideas.

On this page this dialog box to qet quotes. 
http://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/non_navigable/marketing/email/get_quote.html?

I used SPY, XLV, IBM, MSFT

The output is the above with a table.

If you have an account the quote are real time --- via cookie.

How do I get the table into python using 2.6.  The data as list or dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem: the data is actually in an iframe in a frame; you need to be looking at https://www.schwab.wallst.com/public/research/stocks/summary.asp?user_id=schwabpublic&symbol=APC (where you substitute the appropriate symbol on the end of the URL).

Second problem: extracting the data from the page. I personally like lxml and xpath, but there are many packages which will do the job. I would probably expect some code like

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html
import re
re_dollars = '\$?\s*(\d+\.\d{2})'

def urlExtractData(url, defs):
    """
    Get html from url, parse according to defs, return as dictionary

    defs is a list of tuples ("name", "xpath", "regex", fn )
      name becomes the key in the returned dictionary
      xpath is used to extract a string from the page
      regex further processes the string (skipped if None)
      fn casts the string to the desired type (skipped if None)
    """

    page = urllib2.urlopen(url) # can modify this to include your cookies
    tree = lxml.html.parse(page)

    res = {}
    for name,path,reg,fn in defs:
        txt = tree.xpath(path)[0]

        if reg != None:
            match = re.search(reg,txt)
            txt = match.group(1)

        if fn != None:
            txt = fn(txt)

        res[name] = txt

    return res

def getStockData(code):
    url = 'https://www.schwab.wallst.com/public/research/stocks/summary.asp?user_id=schwabpublic&symbol=' + code
    defs = [
        ("stock_name", '//span[@class="header1"]/text()', None, str),
        ("stock_symbol", '//span[@class="header2"]/text()', None, str),
        ("last_price", '//span[@class="neu"]/text()', re_dollars, float)
        # etc
    ]
    return urlExtractData(url, defs)
```

When called as

```
print repr(getStockData('MSFT'))
```

it returns

```
{'stock_name': 'Microsoft Corp', 'last_price': 25.690000000000001, 'stock_symbol': 'MSFT:NASDAQ'}
```

Third problem: the markup on this page is presentational, not structural - which says to me that code based on it will likely be fragile, ie any change to the structure of the page (or variation between pages) will require reworking your xpaths.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @hugh I would to get the data from that page. Then, use the new found skills and code for other pages, Thanks for ideas. Its there any way to scape that page. Add authenation and get real time data. I only need the data presented. The sybmol list 50+ ....   Again, thank very much for your effort. I need to learn how to scape that page......

Comment: Its completely broken, now that I started using lxml, can you tell me how you fixed it, if you do fix it.

Comment: @user428862: in what way is it "completely broken"? The code above still seems to work for me.

Comment: @ hugh, Its works today.  it didnt b4 on my machine.  i did not know you replied. Can you help with extracting table from http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/DQBeta.aspx..... pick MSFT, thanks This is not my target site. the target site has data presented in the same format and with authication.

Answer (score 5):

Use something like Beautiful Soup to parse the HTML response from the web site and load it into a dictionary.  use the symbol as the key and a tuple of whatever data you're interested in as the value.  Iterate over all the symbols returned and add one entry per symbol.

You can see examples of how to do this in Toby Segaran's "Programming Collective Intelligence".  The samples are all in Python.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know of this source. Do you know where in the book, my topic is handled. I am a noob at this.

Comment: See Chapter 3: Discovering Groups.

Comment: I looked and tried to do it. I couldnt get it done. I have BSoup loaded it downloaded page. But, I couldnt figure out how to get symbols, the dialog box. Second. I could figure the code dropped to figure out what I needed from what was parsed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought of using yahoo's quotes api?
see: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22YHOO%22

You will be able to dynamically generate a request to the website such as:
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22YHOO%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

And just poll it with standard a http GET request. The response is in XML format.

Comment: I have data from Yahoo up and running.   I use cvs download parse into table.  I'm not skilled with Http Get and XML format.

Comment: An http get is a standard http request that you do with your browser. Use httplib2, the object http.request(the_url,"GET") and you will get a response with the xml to parse. Using this and xml does not requires skill, but if you want to know the abc of the web, maybe you should take a look at it. Since XML is just text, parse it and map the informations you want into your logic objects and job's done.

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib has a module that gets historical quotes from Yahoo:

```
>>> from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(quotes_historical_yahoo('IBM', date(2010, 11, 12), date(2010, 11, 18)))
[(734088.0,
  144.59,
  143.74000000000001,
  145.77000000000001,
  143.55000000000001,
  4731500.0),
 (734091.0,
  143.88999999999999,
  143.63999999999999,
  144.75,
  143.27000000000001,
  3827700.0),
 (734092.0,
  142.93000000000001,
  142.24000000000001,
  143.38,
  141.18000000000001,
  6342100.0),
 (734093.0,
  142.49000000000001,
  141.94999999999999,
  142.49000000000001,
  141.38999999999999,
  4785900.0)]
```

Comment: Thanks Im really trying ot get the data from a broker. I need intraday prices.