# Adding column In table with Python

Tags: python, logging

Im trying to create a logging output using python 2.6.

The data come a database. What I would like to do is add a column to all rows with a time stamp `= strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`. There are about 50 rows.

Then drop into a csv table.

`.append` and `.extend` seem to add rows but not columns. Is there an easy way to do this?

Should I splice data to add col?

Comment: How are you reading the database?

Comment: Please give an example of your data. Is it a single row you want to add this to? Is it dict or a list? Or do you have a list of dicts? Or list of lists? Please specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick example:

If you have a two-dimensional list like

```
l = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8],
     [9,10,11,12]]
```

then `l.append(13)` gets you

```
l = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8],
     [9,10,11,12],
     13]
```

which I assume is what you mean by "it adds rows, not columns".

You probably want `l[0].append(13)` which gives you

```
[[1,2,3,4,13],
 [5,6,7,8],
 [9,10,11,12]]
```

If you want to do this for all rows, you could use

```
for row in l:
    row.append(13)
```

giving you

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 13], 
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 13], 
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Of course, in your case you will want to add the timestamp instead of `13`, but the principle is the same. And then it's trivial to convert the 2D list into a csv object.

Comment: Cool, yeah thanks How would do this  [[13, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
 [13, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
 [13, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

Comment: `for row in l: row[0:0] = [13]`. It's called [slice assignment](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: Ran into this error insert "13", pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'append .... fetched ok then "added for row in l:
    row.append(13)" and ran into prob.

Comment: I tried to Create L=[] before fetch. filled L with fetchall. then added above, same prob.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know pyodbc. If you could somehow get the database table into a two-dimensional list (like I assumed you already had) this should work.

Comment: I'm a hack at this. Get the Data:  sqld = csr.fetchall(), I tried l= list(sqld). Same prob. What else could I try? I use zip to clean tables. Could I use here?

Comment: data Looks like [(1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8), (9,10,11,12)]

Comment: OK, so you've got a list of tuples which are immutable and therefore don't have an append method. Try `LL = [list(x) for x in L]` and then apply the same as above to the new 2D list `LL`.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I dont know what the last step wasbut worked nicely   BTW Any help with this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219007/download-prices-with-python.  I have BSoup loaded, but cant get real help with this.

Comment: You're welcome. That last step was a list comprehension that converts each tuple `(1,2,3,4)` into a list `[1,2,3,4]` etc., so that it becomes possible to modify. Tuples are immutable.